# I want to add a new row to UITableView with the click of a Button

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

when I click the add button it return the error 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'

```
import UIKit 

class PlacesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var addPointTableArray = [""]
    @IBOutlet weak var addPointableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addPointableview.delegate = self
    }

    @objc @IBAction func addPointButton(_ sender: Any) {
        addPointableview.beginUpdates()
        addPointableview.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: addPointTableArray.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        addPointableview.endUpdates()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:    IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = addPointableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:  "addCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! AddPointCellCell
        cell.addPointTextfiedl.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.addPointTextfiedl.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(addPointButton(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        addPointableview.beginUpdates()
        addPointableview.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: addPointTableArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        addPointableview.endUpdates()
        return cell
    }

}
```

I have checked my table and add button I don't know where the error is coming from

Answer (score 0):

You should not be inserting rows in your `cellForRow(at:)` method.

You also need to update your data model so that there is data for these new indexPaths. The table view will ask for data for the cells at the new indexPaths in order to refresh, and if the data model is not updated to contain data for the new cells you may crash.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper way to add rows in a table view.
First of all you don't have to add rows in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.

The table view data source needs to be changed in order to achieve what you want.
Since you wrote this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

The table view always expect to have two rows.

### Solution

So, first of all you have to return the number of the array because it tells the table view how many rows will be shown.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return addPointTableArray.count
}
```

Then, if you want to add a new row, you need to update the array **before** calling `insertRows(at:with:)`:

```
@IBAction func addPointButton(_ sender: Any) {
    addPointTableArray.append("New element")
    addPointableview.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: addPointTableArray.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}
```

You don't need to call `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` because you're only inserting, those methods are needed for multiple manipulation.

Finally, as I said before, change the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` to this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = addPointableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:  "addCell", for: indexPath) as! AddPointCellCell
    cell.addPointTextfiedl.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.addPointTextfiedl.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(addPointButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

So at the end your class would look like

```
import UIKit

class PlacesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var addPointTableArray = [""]
    @IBOutlet weak var addPointableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addPointableview.dataSource = self
        addPointableview.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func addPointButton(_ sender: Any) {
        addPointTableArray.append("New element")
        addPointableview.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: addPointTableArray.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return addPointTableArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = addPointableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addCell", for: indexPath) as! AddPointCellCell
        cell.addPointTextfiedl.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.addPointTextfiedl.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(addPointButton(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

}
```

I suggest you to re-study how to implement a basic table view before dealing with insertion/removing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I appreciate your advice also. regards

Comment: Please if you appreciate, vote up or set as best if you think it is

Answer (score 0):

A table view displays the contents of the data source array. If you are using `insertRows` you have to append an item to the data source before updating the UI.

Never call `insert/deleteRows` in `cellForRowAt`. And `beginUpdates/endUpdates` is pointless for a single insert operation.

```
class PlacesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var addPointTableArray = ["0"]

    @IBOutlet weak var addPointableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addPointableview.delegate = self
        addPointableview.datasource = self
    }

    @objc @IBAction func addPointButton(_ sender: Any) {
       let insertionIndex = addPointTableArray.count
       let indexPath = IndexPath(row: insertionIndex, section: 0)
       addPointTableArray.append(String(insertionIndex))
       addPointableview.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return addPointTableArray.count // never hard-code the return value, return the number of item in the data source
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = addPointableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addCell", for: indexPath) as! AddPointCellCell   
       cell.addPointTextfiedl.tag = Int(addPointTableArray[indexPath.row])
       // assign values of the data source array to UI elements
       cell.addPointTextfiedl.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(addPointButton), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)    
       return cell    
     }   
   }
```